# embedding cshtml in dll for MEF pluggable site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I'm trying to get a pluggable archetecture with MEF and MVC3 (cshtml).

Everything is compiling and the initial - non plugin page loads. when i try to navigate to the plugin area i get a

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream

error.

When i break in the AssemblyResourceVirtualPathProvider.FileExists i see that it returns false for base.FileExists(virtualPath)

i have ensured that the path is correct and the view is set as an embeded resource.

Is there any way of validating that the view is being added as a resource? a tool to look in dlls perhaps?

I can post more code if necessary - please specify if so.

thanks

[edit - adding code]

here is the code for the AssemblyResourceVirtualPathProvider: [monobin.com](http://monobin.com/__f5a78e581)

Comment: Please provide more code (especially the FileExists and related methods).

Comment: Can you confirm you've got the `Build Action` set to Embedded?

Comment: defo: "i have ensured that the path is correct and the view is set as an embeded resource."